# shiny app embedded video not working (browser dependent)

Tags: r, video, shiny-server, shiny

I have embedded a video in my app using this line:

```
tags$video(src = "myVideo.mp4", type = "video/mpeg4", controls = NA, width = "100%")
```

I've written the app on my Mac, and when I publish and view it, the video plays perfectly in Safari, but it doesn't show anything in Chrome or Firefox. The majority of users will not be using Safari so this is a bit of an issue. Any other formats that would work better? I thought mp4 shouldn't have this type of issue.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Try `type="video/mp4"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a bad video encoding. Used a converter, kept it as mp4, and it seems to work. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I change the name of my video from `My Video 2016 03 01.mp4` to `MyVideo20160301.mp4`. Seemed to work.